# How do I create a custom gunicorn setup with Django on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

Django project structure

```
AppName
│   main.py
│   manage.yaml   
│   app.yaml  
│   gunicorn.conf.py  
│
└───AppName
│   │   wsgi.py
│   │   settings.py
```

app.yaml

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto

entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :8080 AppName.wsgi:app

# [END django_app]
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
import multiprocessing

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

The application works without this line.

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :8080 AppName.wsgi:app
```

But I need to have a custom gunicorn.conf.py in order to set the number of workers dynamically.

I've been following this doc. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime

I have tried many variations of that line but I can't seem to get it to work.

Also is setting the number of workers going to keep the application on? My goal here is to be safe in case of any spikes as well as have a worker always already booted up even if the application hasn't been used in a while.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are following the documentations for the recommended app.yaml entrypoint, your actual gunicorn.conf.py configuration is probably using [sync workers.](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#sync-workers)

I recommend to use async workers, as per the [Gunicorn documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#async-workers), "The asynchronous workers available are based on Greenlets (via Eventlet and Gevent)", and the sync workers you have right now handles a single request at a time.

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#workers), if your worker class requires additional dependencies such as gevent or tornado, those dependencies will need to be declared in your application's `requirements.txt`.

Also make sure that in your `requirements.txt` you have added the specified version for `gunicorn` as stated [here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup)

Nonetheless, as you mentioned here:

> Also is setting the number of workers going to keep the application on? My goal here is to be safe in case of any spikes as well as have a worker always already booted up even if the application hasn't been used in a while.

If you really want to keep the application on at all cost, I highy suggest you to use [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/) (Google Kubernetes Engine). You can not only choose in an easy way the capacity and the power of your workers but you can also use `deployments` to have [multiples replicas](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/deployment) of your application running.

You don't have to worry if one of your apps crash or fails since GKE will struggle to accomplish your 'desired state', which in this case is having 'x' apps running all the time.

I hope this helps.