# Why can't gunicorn utilize more workers (google app engine)?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

In documentation you can find https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime.
It says that not having gunicorn.conf.py that sets multiple workers could increase latency since default worker number is 1 (latency does get high with one worker 800ms). However obeying the recommended gunicorn setup increases the response time by 4 more seconds and sometimes it just fails to deliver.
My entrypoint:
`entrypoint: gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :$PORT main:app`

Entrypoint with one worker:
`entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you make sure that the number of workers you specify should match the instance class of your [App Engine app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices). Also have a look at this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69433423/18265702) link and also Can you share the error message?

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni it is in flexible environment so the instance auto scales. I'm unsure that I can choose the size of an instance. There is no error message, it just becomes unresponsive and timeouts for most of the requests when the gunicorn conf with (cpu_count) * 2 + 1 is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470537/18265702) by @Christopher Rodriguez Conde,

> As long as you are following the documentation for the recommended app.yaml entrypoint, your actual gunicorn.conf.py configuration is probably using [sync workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#sync-workers).
>
> I recommend using async workers, as per the [Gunicorn documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#async-workers), "The asynchronous workers available are based on Greenlets (via Eventlet and Gevent)", and the sync workers you have right now handle a single request at a time.
>
> As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#workers), if your worker class requires additional dependencies such as gevent or tornado, those dependencies will need to be declared in your application's `requirements.txt`.
>
> Also make sure that in your `requirements.txt` you have added the specified version for `gunicorn` as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#application_startup).